# How do I get leads from multiple facebook pages using a facebook app and a webhook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to get leads from facebook pages using a facebook app and a webhook.  I'm using Zapier right now(which is working) but I'm trying to create a custom solution to replace Zapier.  My webhook is working for one page, but I have about 10  facebook pages and each page has their own, separate lead forms.  I've used the Lead Ads Testing Tool to check to see if my facebook app is listed and their is only one page that lists my facebook app - the one that is working. I can't figure out how to add my facebook application to the other pages. What I've tried: I went into Business manager and made sure that my facebook user account is listed under each page and verified that I'm an admin on all those pages. I also tried to add or assign a CRM to the pages under Integrations->Lead Access in Business Manager but my facebook application named TestApp is not accessible via the search(see 2nd image), in fact, no CRMs are searchable except for Zapier.[image: Image showing my facebook app is connected] [image: Image showing CRMs for a different page - TestApp is not available]Questions: How can I subscribe each page to my facebook app so leads from all my pages will be sent to my webhook?  Or do I need to create a facebook app and  webhook for each page?

Comment: Use the API to subscribe instead of the UI, how that works is explained somewhere in the documentation.